# Empathy: Account Manager Error "Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)"

Tags: 11.10, empathy, telepathy

I run Ubuntu Ocelotin italian language and since a week I get a strange error by Empathy:
"Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)"
It seems that telepathy cannot contact the account manager,.
As said, Empathy starts but the most important part of it, the account manager, doesn't. I tried to purge Empathy and Telepathy, to disable its repository with Ubuntu Tweak, but without results. What do I have to do, I need to use Empathy !
Greetings,
Francesco

Comment: even if I launch it from terminal I obtain the following:    folks-DEBUG: individual-aggregator.vala:305: Setting primary store IDs to defaults.
folks-DEBUG: individual-aggregator.vala:333: Primary store IDs are 'eds' and 'system'.

folks-WARNING **: Error preparing Backend 'telepathy': Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

Comment: I still couldn't solve it. It works on another computer, but it doesn't on my pc.

Comment: It seems to affect Ubuntu 12.04 too: may it dipend from dbus: http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-telepathy/2011-11/msg00229.html

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Temporary workaround:

```
killall -9 empathy
killall -9 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
```

Then restart Empathy. It should work until it breaks again.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same message, but only if empathy is a start up application.  If you deactivate empathy from starting at start up and activate it manually the problem seemed to go away.  My feeling is that empathy is starting prior to telepathy being ready to accept its request.